# python lxml eats a lot of memory when only one element exist

Tags: python, memory, lxml

all,

I have a huge xml file, and need to first check the value of "status" tag in the root. It eat even double of the memory than when processing tag = item. And I have no idea why. 
I use lxml version 2.3.2, and python 2.7.3 in ubuntu 14.04.
Structure of the xml is as below:

```
<root>
<status>s_value</status>
<count>c_value</count>
<items>
<item>***</item>
<item>***</item>
...
</items>
</root>
```

I try to process the file as below (ignore the namespace):

```
from lxml import etree
status = etree.iterparse('file.xml', tag='status')
for event, element in status:
    value = element.text
    element.clear()
del status
```

This code still eat a lot memory and also take long time (15s). 
I tried to use a "break", and it gets the same result, but is much faster (1s), can not see the memory usage, as it is fast.

```
from lxml import etree
status = etree.iterparse('file.xml', tag='status')
for event, element in status:
    value = element.text
    element.clear()
    break
del status
```

It seems something happen after run the first status, but as there is only one element in status, I am wondering what is processed? 
Dose any one has any idea what is happening? Thanks very much

Comment: @Backtrack, yes, that is why I try to use "break" to see the performance, but as in the "status" loop, it should have only one element, then with or without "break", I think it should be the same.

Comment: Also, remember that [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is a wrapper for [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/), so the culprit might not necessarily be the Python wrapper...

Comment: What do you mean by *It eat even double of the memory than when processing tag = item*, double in comparison to what exactly? Also how large is your file?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, thanks for your reply. I am checking the CPU and Memory usage in ubuntu by using "ps aux". If using the same method of etree.iterparse('file.xml', tag='item'), the memory cost is about 5%-8%. But when process tag = 'status', it can use about 15%-20%. My xml file is about 400M.

Comment: @Jens, thanks for your info. Can you explain more about how can it effect the memory usage here? Thanks very much

Comment: @zhihong What you're seeing is the result of Python code using an external C library to process XML, and it's difficult to nail down the actual root of your observed problem without investigating the entire stack. I would almost suggest to post this to the [lxml mailing list](https://mailman-mail5.webfaction.com/listinfo/lxml).

Comment: @Jens, thanks, I will post it in the mailing list.

Comment: just a idea, why you dont use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmljson ?

Comment: @wu4m4n, thanks for the comment, as our requirement is to convert xml to csv, that is why we use ET lib to do the work. But I think you are right, if xmljson makes it easier to process huge xml file, you can use xml to json, then to csv.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems something happen after run the first status

Yes. It is vainly searching for the second status.

Without the break, your loop must process the entire file. The loop searches for *all* of the `<status>` tags. Without reading the file to the end, it cannot know if it has found the final tag.

Alternatively, with the break, the loop stops immediately.

Consider these two loops:

```
for i in range(1000000):
    if i == 1:
        print(i)

for i in range(1000000):
    if i == 1:
        print(i)
        break
```

Hopefully, you can see that the first loop must run one million times, even though it will find the one-and-only `1` immediately.

Similarly with your code, your non-break loop must run over a bajillion lines, even though it will find the one-and-only `<status>` immediately.